# Using emf compare from code?

Tags: java, eclipse-emf

I have two emf models A and B where B only differs from A because it has an extra child node.

Now I would like to use emf compare from code to do:

1) Read model A and B and create model C which is a merged model from A and B. Basically this corresponds to A + the extra nodes from B.

I have looked at:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf.compare/examples/org.eclipse.emf.compare.examples.standalone/src/org/eclipse/emf/compare/examples/standalone/ExampleLauncher.java?view=co&root=Modeling_Project

But I don't see how I can compute the final merged model using the code:

```
DiffModel diff = CompareUtils.compare(model1, model2, Collections.<String, Object> emptyMap());
CompareUtils.merge(diff);
```

Any examples that shows how to compute the merged model??

I have now tried:

```
      private void bob() {
        ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
        Map extensionMap = (Map) resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry()
            .getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("xmi", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
        try {

      Region region01 = StatemachineFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createRegion();
      addResourceToModel(resourceSet, region01, "st1.xmi");
      State state01 = StatemachineFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createState();
      state01.setName("aaaa");
      region01.getState().add(state01);
      if (state01.eResource() == null) {
        System.out.println("state01 NOT contained in resource!");
        return;
      }

      Region region02 = StatemachineFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createRegion();
      addResourceToModel(resourceSet, region02, "st2.xmi");
      State state02 = StatemachineFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createState();
      state02.setName("bbbb");
      region02.getState().add(state02);
      if (state02.eResource() == null) {
        System.out.println("state02 NOT contained in resource!");
        return;
      }

      final MatchModel match = MatchService.doMatch(region01, region02,
          Collections.<String, Object> emptyMap());
      final DiffModel diff = DiffService.doDiff(match, false);
      final List<DiffElement> differences = new ArrayList<DiffElement>(
          diff.getOwnedElements());
      MergeService.merge(differences, true);

      // Prints the results
      addResourceToModel(resourceSet, match, "match.xmi");
      addResourceToModel(resourceSet, diff, "diff.xmi");

      if (match.eResource() != null)
        System.out.println(ModelUtils.serialize(match)); // Throws an
                                                         // exception!
      if (diff.eResource() != null)
        System.out.println(ModelUtils.serialize(diff));

    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  private void addResourceToModel(ResourceSet resourceSet, EObject obj,
      String path) {
    Resource res = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI(path));
    res.getContents().add(obj);
  }
```

But the line:

```
  if (match.eResource() != null)
    System.out.println(ModelUtils.serialize(match)); // Throws an
                                                     // exception!
```

even though match.eResource() != null

I get this error:

```
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$IOWrappedException: The object 'statemachine.impl.StateImpl@11ce012 (name: bbbb)' is not contained in a resource.
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLSaveImpl.endSave(XMLSaveImpl.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLSaveImpl.save(XMLSaveImpl.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doSave(XMLResourceImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.save(XMLResourceImpl.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.emf.compare.util.ModelUtils.serialize(ModelUtils.java:429)
```

I have added Region to a resource based on the documentation here:

[http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/EMF-FAQ#I_get_a_DanglingHREFException:*e.g..2C*.22org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.DanglingHREFException:_The_object_.27com.example.Foo.402f5dda_.28.29.27_is_not_contained_in_a_resource..22_What_do_I_need_to_do.3F](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/EMF-FAQ#I_get_a_DanglingHREFException%3a_e.g..2C_.22org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.DanglingHREFException%3a_The_object_.27com.example.Foo.402f5dda_.28.29.27_is_not_contained_in_a_resource..22_What_do_I_need_to_do.3F)

and the State is contained in the Region so I don't understand why I get the exception...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tul,

The stack trace you get means that one of the 'merged' objects is not contained into a resource : when merging, we copy an object that references a statemachine (which name is 'bbbb'), we then need to reference this state machine from the copied object ... and that statemachine we reference (is it copied or directly referenced from your other model? You should debug to see this) isn't itself contained in any resource.

```
State state02 = StatemachineFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createState();
state02.setName("bbbb");
region02.getState().add(state02);
if (state02.eResource() == null) {
    System.out.println("state02 NOT contained in resource!");
    return;
}
```

This should ensures that "bbbb" is indeed contained in a resource.

After this line :

```
MergeService.merge(differences, true);
```

Could you try to check once more if "state02.eResource() == null" ? If it is, then that is your issue. Otherwise, you'll have to make sure that this doesn't return :

```
for (State state : region01.getState()) {
    if (state.eResource() == null) {
       System.err.println(state.getName() + " is not contained in a resource);
       return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
Model1 targetModel = EcoreUtil.copy(model1);
addResourceToModel(targetModel) // assign the copied model to a resource
MatchModel match = MatchService.doMatch(targetModel, model2,
                    Collections.<String, Object> emptyMap());
DiffModel diff = DiffService.doDiff(match, false);
EList<DiffElement> differences = diff.getDifferences();
for (DiffElement diffElement : differences) {
    MergeService.merge(diffElement, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Your exception:" org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$IOWrappedException: The object 'statemachine.impl.StateImpl@11ce012 (name: bbbb)' is not contained in a resource."*. The  StateImpl@11ce012 (name: bbbb) is in one resource named st2.xmi,but the match elememt is in another resource named "match.xml". The two resources are different and they do not refer each other. So the match element can NOT refer StateImpl. To solve this problem, all elements(state01, state02, match, diff) must be saved in **ONE** resource. The code is:

```
res.getContents().add(stat01);
res.getContents().add(stat02);
res.getContents().add(match);
res.getContents().add(diff);
```

By the way, the condition "`state02.eResource() == null`" is not nessary.